# Adding 2 numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, addition, 32-bit, 16-bit

Hi just started a course in which we learn assembly and we got a question to add 2 numbers of 32 bit in a 16 bit processor. This is our code:

```
                ORIG    8000h
Num1            STR     8091h, 1201h
Num2            STR     8061h, 4f01h
Soma            TAB     2

                ORIG    0000h

                MOV     R1, Num1
                MOV     R2, Num2
                MOV     R3, Soma
                MOV     R4, M[R1]
                ADD     R4, M[R2]
                MOV     M[R3], R4
                INC     R1
                INC     R2
                INC     R3
                MOV     R4, M[R1]
                ADDC    R4, M[R2]
                MOV     M[R3], R4

Fim:            BR      Fim
```

Our problem is that the carry from the first addition isnt being added to the second and we dont know why.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what machine architecture is this for?

Comment: P3 processor, we use a simulator of it. It uses 16 bits

Comment: Pentium 3? It looks like Intel syntax but it isn't really.. In any case, `INC` affects flags, so you loose the Carry bit from the `ADD` by the time you reach the `ADDC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Carry bit is in the Flags register, and is affected by many operations, usually including `INC`.

You have several options to preserve the carry flag resulting from the `ADD`:

- Save the Flags register after the `ADD`, and restore it before the `ADDC`. On Intel this is done with the `pushf` and `popf` instructions.
- Store the Carry bit in a register. On Intel this is done with `setc [8-bit-register]`. Alternatively you could use a conditional jump. (On intel this would be `jc`, jump on carry; this is probably `BRC` in your simulator). A third way is `MOV R4, 0; ADC R4, R4`.
- Reorder or rewrite the code so that there are no flags-altering instructions between the `ADD` and `ADDC`. This is the preferred solution, and I'll continue based on this option.

First, I'll show you how it's done on Intel:

```
; add the low words
mov    ax, [Num1]
add    ax, [Num2]
mov    [Soma], ax

; Add the high words and the Carry bit
mov    ax, [Num1 + 2]
addc   ax, [Num2 + 2]
mov    [Soma +_2], ax
```

Now for the simulator assembly.

(I'm assuming that `MOV  R4, M[R1]` means to put the value at the memory address in `R1` into `R4`).

If the simulator supports an operand syntax like `M[R1 + 1]`, then the need to increment the registers disappears:

```
            MOV     R1, Num1
            MOV     R2, Num2
            MOV     R3, Soma

            MOV     R4, M[R1]
            ADD     R4, M[R2]
            MOV     M[R3], R4

            MOV     R4, M[R1+2]
            ADDC    R4, M[R2+2]
            MOV     M[R3+2], R4
```

Also, you can probably get rid of using `R1, R3, R3` alltogether if the simulator supports `M[Num1]` syntax.

Note that I add `2`, not `1`, since you're adding words, which are 2 bytes long.
Your `INC`s probably need to be doubled (the simulated CPU can access memory at byte offsets, can't it?). For instance the `INC R1` would become:

```
INC   R1
INC   R1
```

which is equivalent to

```
ADD   R1, 2
```

and this shows clearly how the Carry flag gets overwritten.

If the simulator does not support `M[register + constant]` syntax, we can work around that by using the `R4` register, which is unused between the `MOV M[R3], R4` and the `MOV  R4, M[R1]`:

```
            MOV     R1, Num1
            MOV     R2, Num2
            MOV     R3, Soma

            MOV     R4, M[R1]
            ADD     R4, M[R2]
            MOV     M[R3], R4

            MOV     R4, 0
            ADC     R4, R4   ; R4 now contains the carry flag.

            INC     R1       ; Note you probably need to change
            INC     R2       ; these to  ADD R?, 2
            INC     R3

            ADD     R4, M[R1]
            ADD     R4, M[R2]                
            MOV     M[R3], R4
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer! I'll try everything you said and hopefully it will work! It was great help! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the carry before incrementing the values:

```
                ORIG    8000h
Num1            STR     8091h, 1201h
Num2            STR     8061h, 4f01h
Soma            TAB     2

                ORIG    0000h

                MOV     R1, Num1
                MOV     R2, Num2
                MOV     R3, Soma
                MOV     R4, M[R1]
                ADD     R4, M[R2]
                MOV     M[R3], R4
                MOV     R4, R0
                ADDC    R4, R0
                INC     R1
                INC     R2
                INC     R3
                ADD     R4, M[R1]
                ADD     R4, M[R2]
                MOV     M[R3], R4

Fim:            BR      Fim
```